# Spark VectorAssembler Error - PySpark 2.3 - Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with pySpark 2.3.0 and have a very simple Spark dataframe I created to test the functionality of VectorAssembler. This is a subset of a larger dataframe where I only picked a few numeric (double data type) columns:

```
>>>cols = ['index','host_listings_count','neighbourhood_group_cleansed',\
        'bathrooms','bedrooms','beds','square_feet', 'guests_included',\
        'review_scores_rating']
>>>test = df[cols]
>>>test.take(3)
```

> [Row(index=0, host_listings_count=1,
>   neighbourhood_group_cleansed=None, bathrooms=1.5, bedrooms=2.0,
>   beds=3.0, square_feet=None, guests_included=1,
>   review_scores_rating=100.0),  Row(index=1, host_listings_count=1,
>   neighbourhood_group_cleansed=None, bathrooms=1.5, bedrooms=2.0,
>   beds=3.0, square_feet=None, guests_included=1,
>   review_scores_rating=100.0),  Row(index=2, host_listings_count=1,
>   neighbourhood_group_cleansed=None, bathrooms=1.5, bedrooms=2.0,
>   beds=3.0, square_feet=None, guests_included=1,
>   review_scores_rating=100.0)]

From the above it seems to me that there is nothing wrong with this Spark dataframe. So I then create the assembler as shown below and get the shown error. What could possibly have gone wrong?

```
>>>from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
>>>assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=cols, outputCol="features")
>>>output = assembler.transform(test)
>>>output.take(3)
```

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o279.collectToPython. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 5.0 (TID 10, localhost, executor driver):
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined
>   function($anonfun$3:
>   (struct)
>   => vector)    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Values to assemble cannot be null.
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$assemble$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$assemble$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.assemble(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$3.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$3.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:98)
>     ... 16 more
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:333)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply$mcI$sp(Dataset.scala:2768)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2765)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2765)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:2765)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined
>   function($anonfun$3:
>   (struct)
>   => vector)    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Values to
>   assemble cannot be null.  at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$assemble$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$assemble$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.assemble(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$3.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$3.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:98)
>     ... 16 more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stack trace you posted mentions that the problem is caused by null values in the columns being assembled.

You need to deal with `null` values in your `cols` columns.
Try `test.fillna(0, subset=cols)` before calling transform, or alternatively, filter out rows with null values in those columns.