# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Sorry for the duplicate post. I'm creating again another post as those posts are unable to solve my problem.
I'm running ML Regression on pyspark 3.0.1. I'm running it on a cluster of 640 GB memory & 32 worker node.
I have a data set with 33751 rows & 63 columns. I'm trying to prepare the data set for ML regression. So I wrote following code

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, StandardScaler
input_col=[...]
vector_assembler=VectorAssembler(inputCols=input_col,outputCol='ss_feature')
temp_train=vector_assembler.transform(train)
standard_scaler=StandardScaler(inputCol='ss_feature',outputCol='scaled')
train=standard_scaler.fit(temp_train).transform(temp_train)
```

But I'm getting error message at the last line execution

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 169 in stage 57.0 failed 4 
times, most recent failure: Lost task 169.3 in stage 57.0 (TID 5522, 10.8.64.22, executor 11): 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined 
function(VectorAssembler$$Lambda$6296/1890764576:
```

Can you suggest me how do I solve this issue?

Comment: Hey pysparklearner would you check the different Versions that you are using well your  error is due to version mismatch of spark-mllib library with spark-core library and spark-sql library. They all should be of same version. Please check them because I see that the problem is due to the vector assembler user defined function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark VectorAssembler Error - PySpark 2.3 - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419678/spark-vectorassembler-error-pyspark-2-3-python)

Comment: you might have got nulls in the input columns to vector assembler

Comment: @NassereddineBelghith, what version of spark-mllib &  spark-core library and spark-sql library are required to run this?

Comment: @pysparkLearner it doesn't matter since spark 2.x it has to be the same for all (same version for the core and sql , mllib), however I advise you to check also that your dataframe has no prblem you can do this  by df.head(1) and see whether it reads all the columns correctly or not, if you have a problem with that so you need to clean the dataframe